# JComments Send button not responding

Tags: joomla

I have installed JComments on my site, installation went fine but can't post any comment. Send button has no respond. I tried some solutions from other forums but no help. If I change template it is working. Also working on my local machine. 
Can someone help me with this please?
TNX
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPKeA.jpg)

Comment: There's a separate joomla stackexchange site that is the best place to get your answer [joomla.se]

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is caused by a JavaScript conflict somewhere, you should be able to see the error by clicking on F12 and then clicking on "Console" in Google Chrome.

Having said that, it is probably a better idea to use Disqus instead of JComments because many users are already on the platform and because Disqus automatically filters out the spam for you.